# User input requirements for String values

Tags: vba, excel

Alright, I am trying to create a user defined function that will accept one character input, and then return a `String`. Although I couldn't get the Char data type to work for VBA (not sure why?) I was able to get it working fine if I inputted the single character value as a `String`.

Currently, when the UDF is running within Excel, it will work as long as quotes are placed around the String input, as shown:

```
=tradeClass("o")
```

that will work and return the correct result. But what I really would like to do is be able to write the Excel function in this manner:

```
=tradeClass(o)
```

I wrote out code that will concatenate "" onto the ends of my user input:

```
Public Function tradeClass(class As String)
    Dim result As String
    Dim before As String
    Dim after As String

    before = """"
    after = """"

    class = before & class & after  'my attempt to concatenate " on either side of the class input
    Select Case LCase(class)
        Case "s"
            result = "Sale"
        Case "r"
            result = "Redemption"
        Case "i"
            result = "Exchange In"
        Case "o"
            result = "Exchange Out"
        Case "x"
            result = "Ignore"
        Case "k"
            result = "Settle"
        Case "m"
            result = "Transfer"
        Case "w"
            result = "ML PR3 Redemption (No longer in use)"
        Case Else
            result = "Invalid Entry"

    End Select

    tradeClass = result

End Function
```

It returns a `#VALUE!` error in Excel, so I am starting to think that I will always have to enter quotation marks with my character. Is this the case?

Comment: Even built-in functions from excel that take a `String` as input must include the quotation marks, hence I don't think it is possible :(

Comment: Right, thats what I was starting to suspect. I will just have to live with the quotation marks.

Comment: simpLE MAn if you want to post that as an answer I can accept it

Comment: Thank you for your kindness but I think it is more a comment than an answer.  Maybe someone will find a workaround :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't imagine what compelling reason you have to want to do this.  If you were truly determined, there is a hack/workaround/kludge that will allow this to work.

I strongly advise you not to use this, but you asked a question to which I have an answer.  So here goes:

---

When you pass an unquoted string of character(s) to a function in Excel, it assumes that it is a reference to another cell.  This is obvious in a function call such as `=tradeClass(A1)`.  That function will pass the value of the cell A1 to the function tradeClass.

Excel also supports naming cells to make formulas easier to follow.  For example, you could assign the name "StartYear" to cell A1.  So instead of using `=DATE(A1, 1, 1)` you could use `=DATE(StartYear, 1, 1)` which will be easier to maintain.

Now, in your case, we can abuse this power and name a bunch of cells `s`, `r`, `i`, `o`, `x`, `k`, `m`, and `w`.  In the cell named `s` we would enter the letter "s" as the cell's value and so on.  So then when you call `=tradeClass(o)`, Excel will look up the cell named `o` and get its value (which we set to "o") and pass the value "o" of the cell named `o` to your tradeClass function.

---

This is a dreadful abuse of the cell-naming capabilities of Excel and violates all sorts of good programming practice.  But ask, and you shall receive.

### DISCLAIMER: Please do not actually use this.

*One final note: When, someday, someone comes along and changes the value of the cell named `o` to the letter "s", please refer to the above disclaimer.*

Comment: Well it all makes sense now. I will definitely NOT do this. Thank you for explaining WHY Excel requires quotes for a string, and that it doesn't require quotes if it assumes a cell reference. That is the answer I was looking for, although I didn't realize it when I asked.

Comment: As an aside, have any thoughts on why VBA wouldn't let me set my input to type Char?

Comment: Nevermind my last comment, it seems that VBA does not have a data type of Char. I found the primative data types listed here [link](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/standard-vba-data-types.html)

Comment: @AdamJ: Glad I could help.  And I'm even gladder that you won't be using this!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you want this function to work on user input as specified, you're going to need to pass in with quotes. Try out a built-in Excel function, for example:

```
=LEN(String)
```

vs.

```
=LEN("String")
```

The second one gives you 6, while the first one gives you an error.

However, your code would work nicely if the trade classes you're after are in their own column, like this:

[image]

```
Public Function tradeClass(Str As Variant)

Str = CStr(Str) 'force the variant to a string

    Select Case LCase(Str)
        Case "s"
            result = "Sale"
        Case "r"
            result = "Redemption"
        Case "i"
            result = "Exchange In"
        Case "o"
            result = "Exchange Out"
        Case "x"
            result = "Ignore"
        Case "k"
            result = "Settle"
        Case "m"
            result = "Transfer"
        Case "w"
            result = "ML PR3 Redemption (No longer in use)"
        Case Else
            result = "Invalid Entry"
    End Select

tradeClass = result

End Function
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, it is just stating a fact.

Comment: My apologies @simpLEMAn, it looks like we both pointed to the built-in Excel functions

Comment: No worries, just make sure your answer is actually an answer to OP's question.  You will soon be able to write comments; 27 pts to go :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it’s an old question but got the same error and found the reason and something like this worked for me: you shall use `Public Function tradeclass(class)` and then `class = class.address`.  Hope this helps!